# How to select instances with multiple relations?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have some models `Featured_Course_Request`, `Course_Request`, `Response` and `Teacher`. `Featured_Course_Request` `hasOne` `Course_Request` and `Course_Request` `hasMany` `Response` by `Teacher`.

I want to get the only Featured_Course_Requests on which logged in teacher has not responded (have no Response by logged in teacher.) How can I do it?

I am trying to achieve it with the following code but it is not giving correct output.

```
 $featured_course_request = Featured_Course_Resquest::whereRaw('remaining_coins >=  coins_per_click')->where('status', '=', 'open')
    ->whereHas('courseRequest', function($q) use ($teacher){                                                            
    $q->whereHas('responses', function($qe) use ($teacher){
        $qe->where('teacherID', '!=', $teacher->id);
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target nested relations with the dot syntax: `'courseRequest.responses'` further more you'll need `whereDoesntHave` instead of `whereHas`:

```
$featured_course_request = Featured_Course_Resquest::whereRaw('remaining_coins >=  coins_per_click')
    ->where('status', '=', 'open')
    ->whereDoesntHave('courseRequest.responses', function($q) use ($teacher){
        $qe->where('teacherID', '=', $teacher->id);
    })
    ->get();
```